# Can't see all GPO listing for Windows Update

Tags: group-policy

Yesterday, I was working on a Dell computer, installed the GPMC and then, I was able to see all listing for Windows Update GPO. I'm trying to install WSUS...

This morning, I use my normal laptop and I am not able to see the full Windows Update GPO listing. I only see 2 of them.

- Do not display "Intall updates and Shut Down" option in...
- Do not adjust default option to "Install Updates and Shut Down" in...

Yesterday, I was able to manage like 15-18 settings instead of only 2 this morning.

Is anyone know about that?

P.S. My AD rights haven't been changed

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: On my laptop: Windows XP SP3 x86, Dell workstation: Windows XP SP2 x86 and servers: AD:w2k3 and WSUS w2k8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly, the issue was in the GPO settings. Since I created my original GPO onto a french workstation, the GPO has been created in french. So when I logged on my english laptop and search for "Windows Components", I didn't see anything until I get "Composantes Windows", which is in french...